# Altering the max priority on an existing RabbitMQ queue using the management REST API

Tags: rabbitmq

Using the REST API I'm trying to update the priority of an existing queue like so:

```
PUT /api/queues/%2F/TestEvent_ProcessingService HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:15672
Authorization: Basic <--snip-->
cache-control: no-cache   
{
 "durable":true,
 "arguments":{
 "x-max-priority":2
 },
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    "error": "bad_request",
    "reason": "inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'TestEvent_ProcessingService' in vhost '/': received the value '2' of type 'long' but current is none"
}
```

Is there any way to set this value on an existing queue, or do you need to delete the queue and recreate it with a new "x-max-priority" value?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in RabbitMQ's documentation:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html

> do you need to delete the queue and recreate it with a new
> "x-max-priority" value?

Yes.

([cross-posted question here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/E9bpp4z4ylI/DNrums9kAQAJ)).

Comment: What a shame.  You could answer it once here and save everyone a lot of time.....

Comment: My response started with **YES**, which is the answer to the original question.